# Powershell script to map new network drive?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am relatively new to scripting with powershell. I was asked by my employer to see if I can find and write a powershell (or other) script to remap network shares. I have tried time and time again but have had no luck.

We have about 50 users connect to "NetworkShare1" and there are different drives (C, D and E) on this share. We need to switch users over to "NetworkShare2" but keeping the file structure the same. Is there any sort of script or function that would help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: g o o g l e     ok?

Comment: 1) Wrong site. This is a programmer's Q&A site (recommend superuser or serverfault). 2) Use a GPO to map drives for users instead of a script.

Comment: Michael, I've tried and had no luck lol.

Comment: Show us some code!

Comment: Ditto on the GPO approach for this and the move to ServerVault, yet, if you are using mirror file structures on each file share, why are you not just using Windows File Share cluster? It allows you HA/DR across servers and not have stress out about when a single files share falls over. Which sounds like what you are trying to address. That speculative though.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information there about what the drives and directories look like to help you much more then simply showing what a drive mapping looks like:

```
Function MapDrive{   
  param($Letter,$Path)  
  try{
        $strLetter = $Letter + ':'
        net use $strLetter $Path /PERSISTENT:NO
        LogItem -LogEntry "$Letter has been mapped."}
  Catch{
        LogItem -LogEntry "$Letter failed to map."}
}
```

A call looks like this:

```
MapDrive -Letter 'Q' -Path '\\SERVER\FILESHARE'
```

You would need to manipulate the mappings to appear the way you wanted for the user.